# MATLAB : Calculating contrast

Tags: matlab, brightness, contrast

I'm trying to calculate the contrast of the image 'tire.tif' in `Matlab` using this formula [Contrast formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ImT.png)
I did this little program in Matlab with two methods. The problem is that I don't get the same result. Can someone check my code and tell me what did I do wrong.

```
[M,N]=size(I);
Lumi=1/(M*N)*sum(I(:)); % which gives 53.66

Cont_method1=sqrt(1/(N*M)*sum(I(:)-Lumi)^2); % gives 5.478+03
Cont_method2=sqrt(1/prod(size(I))*sum(power((I(:)-Lumi),2))); % gives 9.0292
```

Comment: In method1 you have `sum(err)*sum(err)`, in method2 you have `sum(err*err)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method,

```
Cont_method1 = sqrt( 
                     1/(N*M) * sum( 
                                    I(:)-Lumi 
                                  )^2
                   );
```

computes the sum of `I(:)-Lumi`, then squares the sum. The equation you link takes the sum of squares:

```
Cont_method1 = sqrt( 
                     1/(N*M) * sum( 
                                    ( I(:)-Lumi )^2 
                                  )
                   );
```

This is equivalent to your second method:

```
Cont_method2 = sqrt(
                     1/prod(size(I)) * sum(
                                            power( ( I(:)-Lumi ), 2 )
                                          )
                   );
```

Note that `N*M` and `prod(size(I))` are the same thing, and both equivalent to the more efficient `numel(I)`. And note that dividing the sum by the number of elements is the same as computing the mean using `mean`. So you can simplify:

```
Cont_method3 = sqrt( mean( ( I(:)-Lumi )^2 ));
```

But note that all you're doing here is computing a scaled norm:

```
Cont_method4 = norm(I(:)-Lumi) / sqrt(numel(I));
```